# How can I fix this issue with my simple query with ORDER BY and LIMIT?

Tags: mysql, cmd, error-handling

I'm working MySQL on windows cmd and the command I entered is

```
SELECT name,rank,year FROM movies ORDER BY year DESC LIMIT 10;
```

and I'm getting syntax error saying :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ,year from movies order by year DESC limit 10' at line 1

expected result:

sorting year by descending order and number of rows limit to 10;

Comment: Can you please post full error message?

Comment: You should always mention the version of mysql you are on in the question since the developers are always 'enhancing' the product and what may be ok in an earlier version may not be in a later version.

Comment: I'm using latest version of MySQL 8.0.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`year`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-Y) is the keyword. Can you please escape the keyword by adding `` ` ``  (back tick symbol) around the column name to solve the issue:

```
SELECT name, `rank`, `year` FROM movies ORDER BY `year` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: More likely rank is depending on the version of mysql in use. added in 8.0.2 (reserved)

Comment: @P.Salmon Year is the issue, for safer side, I added rank too.

Comment: Year is a keyword not a reserved word note reserved words have (R) after them in the link you posted.

Comment: @P.Salmon Corrected in the answer

Comment: No, you should not use single quote `'`, you have to use back tick symbol  `\``, or simply copy paste my code

Comment: This is working perfectly after adding ' symbol around the column